# QML camera's preview resolutions

Tags: android, qt, camera, qml

I am working on a camera Andoid app using QML based on Qt 5.5. I need a live filter on the camera's preview and I would like to use the best preview resolution available. In native java I could get all the supported preview resolutions using the method:

android.hardware.Camera::getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

And then choose the best one based on the screen resolution. 
QML on the other hand, will automatically set the preview resolution which usually has aspect ratio 4:3 and this does not cover the hole screen like on the qml declerative-camera example. So is possible to change the preview resolution on a QML display?

Please note that I do not want to just zoom on the default preview to cover the whole screen.

Thanks